# Zend Form Empty Option Element in Select Tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

In a web site I want to crate an empty option tag using zend form.
e.g.

```
<select>
<option></option>
<option>AAAAA</option>
<option>BBBBB</option>
<option>CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

I have tried to do that with multi options array

```
$this->addElement ( 'select', 'selection', array (
                'label' => 'Selection:',
                'multiOptions' => array(''='', 'a'=>'aaaa', 'b'='bbbb')
        ) );
```

But it gave me an html as follows

```
<select>
    <option **label="" value=""**></option>
    <option>AAAAA</option>
    <option>BBBBB</option>
    <option>CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try giving your empty option key an non null/empty value and see if that helps, even a space or dash might help. I presume you want this so you have nothing selected at the beginning. `array('-'='', 'a'=>'aaaa', 'b'='bbbb')`

Answer (score 1):

what is this `'multiOptions'=>array(''=>'', 'a'=>'AAAAA', b=>'BBBBB');`  ??

you did'nt posted code to check, but i am assuming problem, see the code below

```
//initiate form element
$selectElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('select-name', array(
       "label" => "label",
       "required" => true,
    ));
//add multiple options 
$selectElement->addMultiOptions(array(
        "" => "",
        "somethig" => "value",
    ));
```

Comment: Yes multiOptions is one of the parameter passed when creating the select element.

Comment: but i am afraid its not the right way, the i answered is the correct one if i am not wrong. thansk Mate !

Comment: ya i also did the same but it gives option tags as <option label="" value=""></option>. What I need is <option></option>. Anyway thanks!!! :)